How to Test the Cloud Function with Http Trigger
Would like to set up a HTTP trigger - Cloud Function that listens to a POST method and then Cloud Function will parse the payloads and make a post process on it.

Would like to know what is the curl CLI I can use for testing the POST method with payloads? I used curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)" https://cf-scheduler-a.run.app/ but it does not include payloads.
For the HTTP payloads consumer function in cloud function side. It failed to get the payloads. Currently I use request.get_json function, is this the correct function I can use for getting the payloads from the curl POST CLI for testing purpose?

import functions_framework
from markupsafe import escape
def hello_http(request):
    """HTTP Cloud Function.
    Args:
        request (flask.Request): The request object.
        <https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#incoming-request-data>
    Returns:
        The response text, or any set of values that can be turned into a
        Response object using `make_response`
        <https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.make_response>.
    """
    request_json = request.get_json(silent=True)
    return request_json

Thanks a lot!

For testing an HTTP cloud function you can follow this Documentation. For setting up on HTTP trigger cloud function on POST method have a look at this Documentation. Are you getting any error messages? Also can you please share the logs?
